# HTTP Redirect to HTTPS issue with Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, redirect

Here is the issue: we are trying to redirect all traffic from example.com to example.ca for both HTTP and HTTPS. It is working for redirecting https://example.com to https://example.ca, but when redirecting from http://example.com to https://example.ca, for some reason, it is not working.

The example.com is just placeholder without any content in it, we want all traffic go to example.com redirect to example.ca on Apache web server level.

Here are my configuration files in both SSL.conf and the virtual host sites-available/example.com.conf.

In the SSL.conf file

```
Listen 443 https

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    Redirect permanent "/" "https://example.ca/"
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.com/public_html"   
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.com/public_html"
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
Redirect / https://example.ca
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA

</VirtualHost>
```

In the sites-available/example.com.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    Redirect / https://example.ca
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
ServerName example.com
Redirect / https://example.ca
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

I try play around the config file by move around the virtual host blocks and try redirect from http://example.com to https://example.com first then redirect to https://example.ca, but it is not working. when put http://example.com, it go no where, but for https://example.com, it will redirect to the https://example.ca as expected.

Comment: You need to collect more debugging information. We cannot do that for you. 1. what _exactly_ do you mean by "is not working"? Is a redirection header sent to your browser or not, check that using your browser's network console. 2. what does your http server's error log file contain?

Comment: if go to http://example.com , it just getting the error "this site can't be reached", if go for https://example.com then it redirect to https://example.ca as expected.

Comment: That not answer my questions. You do know what your browser's network console is? You do know what a redirection header is? And you do know what an error logfile is?